# template toolkit keep 20 first chrachters in a string

Tags: regex, template-toolkit

I am trying to remove everything from a string except the first 20 characters. But the regex removes the first 20 and keeps the rest. How can i solve this?

Here is my code:

```
[% p.name | remove('(.{20})', '$1') %]
```

I have also tried this:

```
[% p.name.replace('(.{20})', '$1')) %]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex won't match the string whose length is less than 20.

Use:

```
[% p.name.replace('(?<=.{20}).*', '')) %]
```

Or:

```
[% p.name.replace('(.{0,20}).*', '$1')) %]
```

Comment: @Twistar Oh, yes, the replace logic is not right at first. Try my updated.